# Filling a UK landing card for sleeping in airport for transit

Tags: uk, transit, customs-and-immigration

I am flying into an UK airport at night and planned to sleep in the airport for the early flight out of UK in the next morning. My passport allow me to have visa free visit to UK and I have been in UK for a few times.

The flights into and out of UK are operated by two different airlines, so I have to get through the immigration at night and check-in the next morning.

I know that I will need to fill in a landing card upon my arrival in UK. There is a field called 'Contact Address in UK', how should I fill in this field in the form? Did anyone have encounter this situation before and know if there is more extra work need to be done at the immigration?

Comment: Are you planning to actually enter the UK or just stay airside for the night?

Comment: The flight into And out of UK are operated by two different airlines, so I have to get through the immigration at night and check-in the next morning

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You will only need to fill in a landing card if you intend to actually go through immigration, which may or may not be required depending on which terminal you are landing in and departing from.

However if you do need to fill in a landing card, then you should put 'In Transit' in the address field of the card.